# Internal server error by POSTMAN while invoking API

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am trying to make notes app using serverless and AWS. All code works when running on local server and invoking the API (`http://localhost:3000/prod/notes`) with help of Postman all is working fine.

But when invoking API (`https://********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod`) given by APIgateway in Postman, it gives an error - `Internal server error`. I tried stuff like adding CORS, adding headers (`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`) and also debugged in cloudwatch logs. But I'm still not able to identify the problem.

```
cloudwatch log for api - GET /notes HTTP/1.1" 502 36 6ae60bca-eee2-48b7-b08a-9b6d677c69fa Internal server error
```

Comment: are you using serverless framework to deploy this api?

Comment: If you are not using serverless , did you deployed your api. and what is the integration for api?

Comment: @Jatin Mehrotra . Yes i am using serverless framework for deployment of api

Comment: what is behind the API gateway? is it a Lamda function or some other API origin?

Comment: @Amith Jayasekara . it is lambda function. i am using API for invoking lambda function for adding , deleting , reading data in dynamodb

Comment: `Internal server error` typically denotes an unrecoverable error on the server. Check the logs in amazon to see what the underlying error is - the service logs, not the request logs.

Comment: As you mentioned you wanted, to access `/prod/notes`, did you mentioned that path in your serverless.yml file in events section like this 
`events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}' `

Comment: @Sumit Meel, Did you check cloud watch logs of the lambda function for any possible error during the execution of the function. I assume the log you have added here was taken from API gateway level

Answer (score 0):

The logline you've posted here is the HTTP Access Log for API Gateway. It's essentially like an apache or nginx access log, containing just response code and path.

You'll find the bug complete with stack trace by examining the Lambda execution logs for your function.

Log groups for API Gateway are prefixed with `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_apiId/<stageName>`. You're looking for `/aws/lambda/<your-function-name>-<stageName>`.